# Regular function on a variety which is not globally rational

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> I am looking for a particularly simple example of a regular function $f : V \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ for some affine variety $V \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_k$ over a field $k$, which cannot be expressed by a single rational function of $k(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.

Is there such an example if we choose $V = V(X^2+Y^2-1)$ to be the unit circle?

**Added later:** By "expressed" I mean "expressed as a map between sets". The converse question is: Do we find for any regular $f : V \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ two polynomials $p,q \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ such that $q$ has no zeros in $V$, and $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ holds for all $x \in V$?

**Context:** If we allow $V$ to be quasi-affine then there is such an example: Let $V = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{A}^2_k : x^2+y^2=1, (x,y) \neq (0,-1) \}$ and $f : V \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ with
$f(x,y) = \frac{1-y}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{1+y}$ for $y \neq -1$.
This function is well defined and regular. Of course the rational functions $\frac{1-y}{x}$ and $\frac{x}{1+y}$ represent the same element of $k(V)$ but I doubt that we can define $f$ by a single rational equation.

Am I understanding right from the comments that there is no analogous example in the case of a variety?

Comment: What are the $X_i$? By first principles, giving a morphism $f:V\to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is the same as giving an element of $\mathcal{O}_V(V)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: The $X_i$ are indeterminates. I am asking for a morphism, which cannot be described as a function by an equation $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ for some polynomials $p,q$ and for all $x \in V$. This means we cannot choose any such polynomial $q$ without zeros in $V$.

Comment: As Alex Youcis pointed out, what you are asking for is impossible: a morphism to $\mathbb{A}^1$ from a closed subvariety always extends to the ambient. The next best thing you can have is a morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$: for this, take $\frac{Y}{1+X} = \frac{1-X}{Y}$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: I extended my question. Am I understanding your and Alex' comments right?

Comment: If $V$ is affine then there is a natural bijection between the regular functions $V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ and the elements of the coordinate ring of $V$. (If $V$ is projective then the only regular functions $V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ are constants.)

Comment: @ZhenLin: I understand, but I don't see how this answers my question. Did you look at my example?

Comment: Your question could be phrased better. Do you mean to ask whether every regular function $V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ occurs as the restriction of some rational function $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^1$ whose domain contains $V$?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the confusion! I believe that this is not the case and I am looking for simple counterexamples.

Comment: But it's true. Every regular function $V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ comes from a (not necessarily unique) regular function $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^1$, when $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Maybe $V = \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is the most simple example. Every regular function $\mathbb{A}^n_k \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ which is not a polynomial function cannot by expressed by a single rational function, since the denominator has always zeros. But even now we seem to misunderstand each other. Is the current version of my question precise?

Comment: Look: every element of the coordinate ring of $V$ comes from some element of the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^n$, and geometrically this means that every regular function $V \to \mathbb{A}^1$ comes from the restriction of some regular function $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^1$, which are always polynomial functions.

Comment: @ZhenLin: So we always find a polynomial $p \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ with $f(x) = p(x)$ for all $x \in V$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Wow.. I did not expect this. I will prove it for my own. Thank you very much for your help! If you want, you could turn your comment into and answer.

Comment: The only thing to prove is what I said in my first comment, which you seem to already know.